# Post to Twitter, Facebook and Blogs in one App

Tags: facebook, twitter, wordpress

I'm looking for an Web Application which **manages multiple WordPress blogs, my Twitter and my Facebook**.

If I want to post something I can choose which Blog(s) to post to, which Facebook Page and Twitter.

It would also be pretty neat if I could modify the post for Twitter/Facebook (if I have a longer blogpost, I only want a short excerpt on Facebook and only title+link on Twitter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution that fits my needs: http://posterous.com
The [Autopost](http://help.posterous.com/what-is-autopost) Option looks pretty neat!

Answer (score 1):

[Tweet Deck](http://www.tweetdeck.com/) I believe can manage Twitter and Facebook and some other social network sites. Now a wordpress blog on the other hand I don't think it does. There probably are services for Tumblr but not so many for wordpress.